# Java Replace String 2

Tags: java, string, replace

```
I am try to replace below String

 #cit {font-size:16pt; color:navy; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;}
```

With

**#cit {font-size:16pt; color:red; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;}**

i am writting a Java code for this

```
strbuf.toString().replaceAll(Pattern.quote("#cit {font-size:16pt; color:navy;    
text-align:center; font-weight:bold;}"), "#cit {font-size:16pt; color:red;   
text-align:center; font-weight:bold;}");
```

but the String not get replace?
please help me

Comment: Are you sure that you can modify a `toString()` directly?

Answer (score 3):

change

```
strbuf.toString().replaceAll(Pattern.quote("#cit {font-size:16pt; color:navy; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;}"), "#cit {font-size:16pt; color:red; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;}");
```

to

```
strbuf.toString().replaceAll("#cit {font-size:16pt; color:navy; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;}", "#cit {font-size:16pt; color:red; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("navy", "red");
```

Answer (score 1):

I Guess you are using a StringBuffer.

```
strbuf = new StringBuffer(strbuf.toString().replace(
  "#cit \\{font-size:16pt; color:navy; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;\\}"), 
  "#cit \\{font-size:16pt; color:red; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;\\}"));
```

Because:

`toString()` will create a **copy** of the `StringBuffer`. If you replace text in the copy, this will not change `strbuf`!

Whereat `\\` is used to mask { and } as an not-regexp.

Comment: Take care that strbuf is not final.

Comment: +1, actually the most decent answer here IMO given that we don't know how specifically the OP wants to replace "navy" by "red". Also, to everyone that suggests to use `replace()` / `replaceAll()` without saving the result into a variable: this won't work unless you only want to loose CPU time.

Comment: I am unhappy because its thread-unsafe... see, other threads may use the `strbuf`. If i just redeclare the variable it may cause yielding into two objects whereat there only should be one.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
 str.replaceAll(str,"#cit {font-size:16pt; color:red; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use String.replace() to avoid having to deal with regexes in replaceAll()

```
String result = text.replace("#cit {font-size:16pt; color:navy; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;}",
              "#cit {font-size:16pt; color:red; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant do string replace by doing this.

```
mystring.replace("string1", "string2");
```

Instead you should do

```
mytring = mystring.replace("string1", "string2");
```

This is because String is immutable object in java. str.replace wont affect the original str object but instead method returns a new string object.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to change the color?

use:

```
strbuf.toString().replaceAll("navy", "red");
```

Btw.: 
If you really want to replace values in CSS it would be better to insert some kind of markes into the source CSS like *color:${color-to-be-replaced}* and replace that markers because it is more portable and reliable. Think about what will happen if you change the color of source CSS to *green* and forget to change the replacement code.